# Java: Running total for a loop and error: missing return statement

Tags: java, swing

I am still new to Java and I can't figure out how to get it to keep a running total. Any suggestions on what I should look up would be awesome. Thank you for your time.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class OrderingProducts2

{

   public static double main(String[] args)

      {
         // Number of products 
         final int NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS = 5;
         //all of the valid values 
         int[] validValues = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
         //prices that coralate with the values
         double[] prices = {2.98, 4.50, 9.98, 4.49, 6.87};
         //Starting total price of order
         double total = 0.00;
         //Sring for chosing a product to order

         String strProducts;

         int productOrdered;
         //Starting price of unnamed product
         double productPrice = 0.00;
         //boolean used to validate product
         boolean validProduct = false;
         //User input of product number
         strProducts = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the product number you want to order or done");
         //product number being converted to an integer
         productOrdered = Integer.parseInt(strProducts);
         //string for getting the quanity 
         while(productOrdered > -1)
             {       
         String strQuanity;

         int productQuanity;
         //user input of quanity         
         strQuanity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the amount of product " + strProducts);
         //conversion of the quanity to an integer
         productQuanity = Integer.parseInt(strQuanity);
         //validation and totaling of the price of order    

         for(int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS; ++x)

              {

               if(productOrdered == validValues[x])

                  {

                     validProduct = true;

                     productPrice = prices[x];

                     total = productPrice * productQuanity;

                   }                  

             }
             }
         //if there awas a valid out put this message will show
         if (validProduct)

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The price for product " + productOrdered + " is $" + productPrice + ". The price for your ordered item/items so far is $" + total);
         //if output was not valid this message will show
         else

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry1 - invalid product entered");
```

Comment: I would start by having a look at `public static double main(String[] args)`

Comment: If there are problems other than your main function, it would be nice if you could provide a brief overview of what its supposed to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Why is the return type for main `double`?

It should be `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: That's assuming that it "is" the `main` method and not a really badly named `static` method ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double main(String[] args)
```

[according to **j.l.s 12.1.4:Invoke Test.main**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

> Java's `main()` method to execute should be: declared public, static,
>   and void. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared
>   type is array of String. Therefore, either of the following
>   declarations is acceptable:

So either: `public static void main(String[] args)`

or, `public static void main(String... args)`

---

Again, assuming that you are using `public static double main()` method then, you must a return double type value:

This is specified in [**jls-8.4.7 Method body:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7)

> If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time
>   error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally. In other
>   words, a method with a return type must return only by using a return
>   statement that provides a value return; it is not allowed to "drop off
>   the end of its body".

---

```
while(productOrdered > -1)
{
  // your code
}
```

I don't see you have updated(decrement or some other opearation) the `productOrdered` which might cause it to have a value `-1`. be careful about it. I may want it to be checked with `if-else` condition.

Comment: There's nothing stopping the OP from having a method called `public static double main(String[] args)`, is quite valid ;)

Comment: yes, i have added some other line to my answer by assuming that. :) ;) I knew you would be here to catch me from my back :p

Comment: I will hump you and dump you, he he he ;)

Comment: Buy me a drink first ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two immediate issues, but it's difficult to know which one is wrong...(or less correct)...

```
public static double main(String[] args)
```

Is wrong for one of two reasons.  If this is suppose to be you applications main entry point, then it should read...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Otherwise Java won't be able to run your application.

If it's not (and it's just some `static` method you want to run), then you it should have a `return` statement before it exists.  In which case, it's unlikely that you'll be able to run the class until you either provide a implementation of `public static double main(String[] args)` somewhere to call it...

For example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrderingProducts2.main(args);
}
```

**Updated**

In order to generate a running tally, you need to provide some kind of exit value from your loop that the user is capable of entering, in you code you're used `productOrdered`, but you never change that value within the `while` loop.

A better solution might be to validate the `productOrdered` before you enter the loop and use `productQuanity` as the exit value.

In you main loop, you are also not incrementing the total, but you are simply setting it's value...

```
total = productPrice * productQuanity;
```

Instead, you could use something like...

```
total += productPrice * productQuanity;
```

While will increment the total on each loop...

And finally, a runnable example...

```
// Number of products 
final int NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS = 5;
//all of the valid values 
int[] validValues = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
//prices that coralate with the values
double[] prices = {2.98, 4.50, 9.98, 4.49, 6.87};
//Starting total price of order
double total = 0.00;
//Sring for chosing a product to order

String strProducts;

int productOrdered;
//Starting price of unnamed product
double productPrice = 0.00;
//boolean used to validate product
boolean validProduct = false;
//User input of product number
strProducts = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the product number you want to order or done");
//product number being converted to an integer
productOrdered = Integer.parseInt(strProducts);

for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS; ++x) {
    if (productOrdered == validValues[x]) {
        validProduct = true;
        productPrice = prices[x];
    }
}

if (validProduct) {

    int productQuanity = -1;
    do {

        //string for getting the quanity 
        String strQuanity;

        //user input of quanity         
        strQuanity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the amount of product " + strProducts);
        //conversion of the quanity to an integer
        productQuanity = Integer.parseInt(strQuanity);
        //validation and totaling of the price of order    

        if (productQuanity > -1) {
            for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS; ++x) {

                if (productOrdered == validValues[x]) {
                    validProduct = true;
                    productPrice = prices[x];
                    total += productPrice * productQuanity;
                }

            }

        }

    } while (productQuanity > -1);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The price for product " + productOrdered + " is $" + productPrice + ". The price for your ordered item/items so far is $" + total);

} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry1 - invalid product entered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main method should have the following signature, else you would not have an entry point of for your Java application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) // return type is void and not double
```

And also, you don't need a while there, it'll just be an infinite loop. Replace it with an `if`.

```
if (productOrdered > -1) {
```

Comment: That's assuming that it "is" the `main` method and not a really badly named `static` method ;)

Comment: That seems to be the case most likely, as I don't see any other method, nor do I see, another `psvm main` method, and thus, no execution point for this program!

Comment: I agree, but it's still an assumption ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your main method should be

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 //no return values
}
```